# Search multiple attribute by label not by value and use like condition

Tags: product, attributes, collection, layered-navigation

I have a problem, i have 2 attributes both are multiselect. When i apply search one of them is text box, now how search query would frame because it would on the basis of label not value.
Please help

Comment: Not fully clear to me ?

Comment: i mean to say i have a custom search with 2 elements. one is text box and other is drop down. but in the admin both the attributes are multiselect so now how get the product collection

Comment: Where do you want to show collection ? custom phtml or in default magento list page.

Comment: it is a custom phtml page.. please help

Comment: Sorry for the late response.For that you have to override the core products listing blocks and set grid/collection on your custom phtml.check this link [http://www.excellencemagentoblog.com/magento-collection-paging]